# why override to nothing is not good approach in subclasses

Tags: design-patterns

I'm reading Head First Design Patterns,
in first chapter, the author tries to explain a design approach. He first shows a problem then tries to solve it by using design patterns.

Let's say if I have a `Duck` base class:

```
class Duck
{
   swim();
   quack();
   display();
}
```

and a derived class `RubberDuck`,

```
class RubberDuck : Duck
{
   quack(); //override to nothing
}
```

He said if `RubberDuck` doesn't quack I have to override it to nothing. **Why?**

I think simply if `RubberDuck` doesn't quack I don't add it to `RubberDuck`. So there will be no override, will be like:

```
class RubberDuck : Duck
{
   //other methods
}
```

And he said:
*So we know using inheritance hasn’t worked out very well, since
the duck behavior keeps changing across the subclasses, and it’s
not appropriate for all subclasses to have those behaviors.*

**Why?**

If i don't override any method, I will not call that methods implementing subclass object in code. I mean if I don't use any ability it means I don't have that ability, whats wrong with that?

Comment: Why on earth is this tagged with "Java"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't override a method, the method will be inherited from the base class. Thus `RubberDuck` will `quack` as `Duck` does.

That's exactly what inheritance is for. Otherwise, what would be it's use?

If you override a method, you have to call `base.Quack()` if you still want the same behavior as the base class has.
Not overriding the method is the same as:

```
public void Quack()
{
    base.Quack();
}
```

The only reason to override the method, thus, is to change or extend it.

Aggregation might behave more like what you expected, for example:

```
public interface IDuck
{
    void Quack();
}


public class RubberDuck : IDuck 
{
    private readonly Duck duck = new Duck();

    public void Quack() 
    {
        this.duck.Quack();
    }
}
```

vs:

```
public class RubberDuck : IDuck 
{  
    public void Quack() 
    {
        // not doing anything, but we still need to implement the method since it's defined by IDuck
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In that book, only the `display()` method is abstract, the base class provides default implementations for all other methods, like `quack()`, `swim()` etc. So it's rather this:

```
class Duck
{
    swim() {
        // do some swimming
    }

    quack() {
        // do some quacking
    }

    abstract display();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be familiar that there is no multiple inheritance in java so if you extend another subclass from rubbercock and if the subclass quaks then it should be overridden in rubbercock else the subclass has to define a new quak method but cant inherit/override it from rubbercock..